# htaccess при существующей директории

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-программирование

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend)
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ frontend/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^audio/(.*)$ frontend/audio/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ frontend/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(backend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/index.php
```

Вот-такой htaccess есть.
При переходе по домену - переходит во фронтэнд, всё ок.
А при переходе по ссылке /backend/ - переходит в бекенд, ок. Но тут ещё момент, эта папка есть! хотя даже если переиминовать её, и переписать htaccess под другую папку, всё работает.

но вод что-то около /backend/login/ - уже не отрабатывает

.htaccess backend-a

```
AddDefaultCharset utf8

 Options -Indexes
 DirectoryIndex index.php

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
 ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htaccess backend-а
     AddDefaultCharset utf8

```
 Options -Indexes
 DirectoryIndex /backend/index.php

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /backend/index.php

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
 ErrorDocument 404 /backend/login
```